# Solr api throws Invalid Number error for Range filter query on TrieDoubleField

Tags: solr

I have a price field that is defined as double (solr.TrieDoubleField). When I query **fq=(price:[0 TO 4.79])** using solr client  it works perfectly fine.

However, when i use the solr api for doing the same then the following error is shown

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Number: [0 TO 4.79]
    at org.apache.solr.analysis.TrieTokenizer.reset(TrieTokenizerFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:959)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:765)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:300)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:142)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:160)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:150)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
```

I am using solr 4.5

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Apparently the query parameter were getting encoded before sending to standalone solr server where it could not understand the square brackets properly.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the query parameter were getting escaped before sending to standalone solr server where it could not understand the square brackets properly